# Unable to access blob via CNAME URI

Tags: azure, uri, blob, blobstore, cname

I created a storage account and created a public folder (called static).  Inside static I pushed one file test.swf.  Now from any browser I can navigate to myproject.blob.core.windows.net/static/test.swf and get the option to load or save the file.  What is odd though is I set up a CNAME (static.mydomain.com) on my domain to point to myproject.blob.core.windows.net.  I waited for DNS to do its magic.  I verified (with ping) that both myproject.blob.core.windows.net and static.mydomain.com pointed to the same IP.  However, with all this 'sameness' using static.mydomain.com/static/test.swf gives the following error xml back:

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidUri</Code>
    <Message>The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
             RequestId:a172a9cf-b60e-451e-9732-b715276b03d0 
             Time:2012-06-13T23:06:44.5477230Z
    </Message>       
    <UriPath>http://static.mydomain.com/static/test.swf</UriPath>
</Error>
```

Even trying http:///static/test.swf gives that error message.  So what did I miss in this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides creating a CNAME and pointing it to your "blob storage domain" (representing your storage account), you also need to validate that CNAME by pointing an other CNAME to **verify.azure.com**.

[image]

You can read all about this on MSDN: [How to Register a Custom Subdomain Name for Accessing Blobs in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee795179.aspx) (note that this guide is for the 'old' portal).

Comment: This fixed it - thanks!  It can take a while for the DNS to propagate so give it time.

Comment: this is the article I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-custom-domain-name

Answer (score 0):

The link included in the accepted answer is no longer available.

To save anyone else some time you no longer need to create a verification subdomain, instead you can now directly specify a subdomain via the 'Manage Custom Domain' in the Azure portal.

1. Create the CNAME for the subdomain in your DNS records.
2. Login to Azure Portal and select - Containers -> Select Container -> 'Manage Domain'.
3. Enter the subdomain you created.